# Can you buy a DLC via Steam and install it whenever you want to?

Tags: steam, europa-universalis-iv

I'm planning to buy some Europa Universalis IV DLC's due to the steam sales.
What i wanted to know is if i can buy them, and install the DLCs later when i finished my current game or will i be forced to install them the next time i launch the game ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While the other answers about disabling are correct I can't add a comment, so I'll post this is an answer.

In the case of Europa Universalis IV, this is a non-issue as you can activate and deactivate DLC as you please from the launcher that boots when you hit play game.

Comment: Funny how this is actually more relevant than the other solutions for this game.

Comment: I'd also like to comment that DLCs won't show their effects in already started games (though updates do partly).

Comment: I'll accept your answer as it is more precise on eu4, but a last question, if i'm playing a current game on vanilla, then i buy and install `Art Of War`, will i be able to continue the current game with the additionnal content of AOW ?

Comment: It depends what version your EU4 is currently at and therefore what version your current game was created on? Art of War was released with version 1.8 so if your current game is 1.8 or above you should be fine. But if for some reason you've set steam to not auto update and are therefore running on an older version of EU4 pre 1.8 than updating will probably break your save.

Comment: You won't be able to continue the existing savegame with the additions from the AoW-DLC. You will continue playing it without the addon content (with the restriction DMK mentioned).

Answer (score 22):

You can disable DLC for a game in the game properties like this:

[image]

Comment: Can't help but notice your categorisation of Civ5 as 'Platform'

Answer (score 8):

Yes, and you can later add it to your game (or disable if you want that for some reason) right from the game's page in your library by (un)marking the corresponding checkbox:

[image]